# Authentication Pages spec with valid information tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, capybara

I am following Michael Hart'l RoR Tutorial but seem to have a problem getting the authentication_pages test "with valid information" to pass in chapter 8.

Specifically, the test complains that the relevant links are missing from the page, even though when I actually visit the page, they are there just fine. In fact, even when I hard these links into every page, the tests complain that the relevant links are not present.

The tests are below: the failing ones are the ones 'with valid information' - everything apart from the           it { should have_title(user.name) }

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe "AuthenticationPages" do

    subject {page}

    describe "signin page" do
        before {visit signin_path}
        it {should have_content("Sign in")}
        it {should have_title("Sign in")}

        describe "with invalid information" do
            before {click_button('Sign in')}
            it {should have_title('Sign in')}
            it {should have_selector("div.alert.alert-error", text: "Invalid")}


            describe "after visiting another page" do
                before {click_link "Home"}
                it {should_not have_selector("div.alert.alert-error", text: "Invalid")}
            end
        end

    **describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
      it { should have_content('This is the user page')}**
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the error message:

```
......................................FFFF

Failures:

  1) AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should have link "Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
       expected #has_link?("Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should have content "This is the user page"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content('This is the user page')}
       expected #has_content?("This is the user page") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should not have link "Sign in", {:href=>"/signin"}
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
       expected #has_link?("Sign in", {:href=>"/signin"}) to return false, got true
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should have link "Profile", {:href=>"/users/1"}
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
       expected #has_link?("Profile", {:href=>"/users/1"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.74198 seconds
42 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34 # AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should have link "Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:36 # AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should have content "This is the user page"
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35 # AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should not have link "Sign in", {:href=>"/signin"}
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:33 # AuthenticationPages signin page with valid information should have link "Profile", {:href=>"/users/1"}
```

Here's a screenshot of the page after signin
[image]

One of the catches is that I can't sign out now!! (i haven't got to the bit of the tutorial where you actually enable sign out yet).

Here's the markup in _header_html.erb which provides the header to the application:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spec and _header looks fine. While you can signin manually, the problem is in how the data is passed to Capybara, because test results demonstrate that signin was unsuccessful.

Do following things

0) Reinitiate test database

```
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

1) Check Factory in factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name     "John Smith"
    email    "john@example.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

2) Check fields names in '/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb. They should looks like

for 'form_tag' case

```
<%= f.label :email %>
```

OR

for 'form_for' case

```
<%= label_tag :email, "Email" %>
```

3) Check that titles on the buttons match those in spec